# Pandas DataFrame - combining groupby() with transform on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, transform

I want to calculate the root means square errors for different set of experiments.

My toy `df` is this:

```
  experiment reaction  result target
0     A         1        1.5    2.0
1     A         2        1.9    1.6
2     B         1        2.1    2.0
3     B         2        2.4    1.6
```

my ideal output is to add a new columns with the rmse value coming from each experiment:

```
  experiment reaction  result target  rmse
0     A         1        1.5    2.0   0.41
1     A         2        1.9    1.6   0.41
2     B         1        2.1    2.0   0.57
3     B         2        2.4    1.6   0.57
```

to calculate the rmse I am using scipy metrics, where the general function is:

`rmse = metrics.mean_squared_error(results, targets, squared=False)`

I should be able to get it using `groupby()` and `transform()` or `groupby()`, `apply()` and `merge()` but the multiple input is messing my logic up.

Any clever idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
from sklearn import metrics

df['rmse'] = df['experiment'].map(df.groupby('experiment')
                                    .apply(lambda g: metrics.mean_squared_error(
                                        g['result'], g['target'], squared=False)
                                          )
                                 )
```

Or, manually computing the RMSE:

```
tmp = df.pivot(index='reaction', columns='experiment',
               values=['result', 'target'])
df['rmse'] = df['experiment'].map(np.sqrt((tmp['result']-tmp['target'])
                                           .pow(2).mean(axis=0)))
```

Output:

```
  experiment  reaction  result  target      rmse
0          A         1     1.5     2.0  0.412311
1          A         2     1.9     1.6  0.412311
2          B         1     2.1     2.0  0.570088
3          B         2     2.4     1.6  0.570088
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it's clear that you are on the right track with using `groupby()` and `apply()`. The main issue is in applying the RMSE calculation correctly within groups. In your case, the `mean_squared_error` function needs two vectors (`result` and `target`), but using `transform()` attempts to apply the function on each column separately, causing the confusion.

The solution to this problem is to use the `apply()` function instead. The `apply()` function is much more versatile when compared to `transform()`. It allows for user-defined functions that can access and operate on multiple columns at once.

Let's redefine the RMSE calculation function to operate on a DataFrame (the group in this case), calculate the RMSE, and add it as a new column to the group:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np

# Define your DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'experiment': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'reaction': [1, 2, 1, 2],
    'result': [1.5, 1.9, 2.1, 2.4],
    'target': [2.0, 1.6, 2.0, 1.6]
})

# Define a function to calculate RMSE for a DataFrame
def calculate_rmse(df):
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(df['result'], df['target']))
    df['rmse'] = rmse
    return df

# Use apply to execute the RMSE function on each experiment group
df = df.groupby('experiment').apply(calculate_rmse)
```

In this code, `groupby('experiment').apply(calculate_rmse)` splits the original DataFrame into groups based on 'experiment', applies the `calculate_rmse` function to each group, and then concatenates the results back together.

The `calculate_rmse` function receives each group as a DataFrame, calculates the RMSE of 'result' and 'target', adds it as a new 'rmse' column to the group DataFrame, and returns the modified DataFrame. The `apply()` function takes care of concatenating these DataFrames back together into the final result.

This will add a new column 'rmse' to your DataFrame, containing the RMSE of each group ('experiment') according to the 'result' and 'target' columns.